# Can we link external API for a confluence page?

Tags: confluence, confluence-rest-api

I have a requirement where when the user clicks publish button in a Confluence page, need to trigger an external API (post endpoint ) where I can save confluence data in external DB.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Event Listener module](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/confluence/event-listener-module/) and [How to build an Event Listener](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/software-development/atlassian/how-to-build-an-annotation-based-event-listener-for-atlassian-confluence-server/). Basically, you create a plugin that captures the [com.atlassian.confluence.event.events.content.page.PageEvent](https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-confluence/5.9.7/com/atlassian/confluence/event/events/content/page/PageEvent.html). In your case, you might use `PageCreateEvent` or `PageUpdateEvent`. This is for Confluence Server. As for Confluence Cloud, it might be in JavaScript or something.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't feel like developing an addon for it,
 then i recommend using an addon [adaptavist scriprunner](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/confluence/ConfluenceEventListeners.html) :

that's the easiest way to accomplish that (although not free!)

example from their webpage:

```
import com.atlassian.applinks.api.ApplicationLinkService
import com.atlassian.applinks.api.application.jira.JiraApplicationType
import com.atlassian.confluence.event.events.space.SpaceCreateEvent
import com.atlassian.sal.api.component.ComponentLocator
import com.atlassian.sal.api.net.Response
import com.atlassian.sal.api.net.ResponseException
import com.atlassian.sal.api.net.ResponseHandler
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

import 
static com.atlassian.sal.api.net.Request.MethodType.POST

def appLinkService = ComponentLocator.getComponent(ApplicationLinkService)
def appLink = appLinkService.getPrimaryApplicationLink(JiraApplicationType)
def applicationLinkRequestFactory = appLink.createAuthenticatedRequestFactory()

def event = event as SpaceCreateEvent
def space = event.space

def input = new JsonBuilder([
    projectTypeKey    : "business",
    projectTemplateKey: "com.atlassian.jira-core-project-templates:jira-core-task-management",
    name              : space.name,
    key               : space.key,
    lead              : event.space.creator.name,
]).toString()

def request = applicationLinkRequestFactory.createRequest(POST, "/rest/api/2/project")
    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
    .setEntity(input)

request.execute(new ResponseHandler<Response>() {
    @Override
    void handle(Response response) throws ResponseException {
        if (response.statusCode != 201) {
            log.error("Creating jira project failed: ${response.responseBodyAsString}")
        }
    }
})
```